# Can I subclass UIView more concisely in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview

When subclassing UIView in Swift, you are required to have init functions

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame:frame)
    initMyStuff()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    initMyStuff()
}

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
    initMyStuff()
}

internal func initMyStuff()
{
    // Init class variables and setup constraints here
}
```

Surely there is a better way to do this. At the very least, what would a better naming convention be for that initMyStuff function? Maybe there is a way extend UIView to have a single custom initializer function I can override in my custom classes?

Comment: Why is your code so repetitious? If your subclass is instantiated from a nib (storyboard etc.), `initMyStuff` is going to be called _twice_. Is that really what you want?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  The answers to this question are going to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Heh I didn't even know about Code Review. I'll check it out.

Comment: @JAL Stub code is off-topic on Code Review. This question was [cross-posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/131745/9357) and put on hold there.

Comment: @200_success well I would have hoped that the OP would have read the rules of CR and implemented the stubbed out methods before posting.  Can't win them all...

Comment: I have people on Code Review telling me to leave the question here. If people spent half as much time answering the question as they did arguing about where it should be posted, I could have marked an answer and awarded points already.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a convenience initializer like so :)

```
convenience init(someValue: String) {
    self.init(frame : CGRectZero)
    .....
}
```